# C# - How to add a Column with it's name being a Date to a DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to add custom columns to a `DataTable` and I can't get this to show up properly I have tried setting up the column names to be a `DateTime` but when I do that it doesn't show any data.

```
var report = new DataTable();
report.Columns.Add("Material");
report.Columns.Add("Unit");

report.Columns.Add($"{new DateTime(2018, 9 , 13)}", typeof(float));
var column = new DataColumn {DataType = typeof(float), ColumnName = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()};
report.Columns.Add(column);
report.Columns.Add("2018-09-14", typeof(float));


report.Rows.Add(new object[] {"foo", "bar", 25.4f, 33.1f, 12});
```

[Result of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9w1t.png)

As you can see only the column that's name is typed in shows any data. How can I name my `DataTable` columns as dates and have it work?

**Edit 1**
This is how I do my data binding:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Report.DefaultView}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
```

Comment: Just as an info: I would suggest not to bind a DataTable and using a List to your view. Makes it a lot easier and cleaner and you could just add an entry to the list and you would follow the MVVM pattern which is, in my opinion, the best way to write a WPF application.

Comment: try add square brackets: `[some name here]`

Comment: Would the hardcoded date be the way the desired column name should look like?

Comment: @Filburt Ideally, yes, that is how I would like them to look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using DataGrid of WPF, then the "/" charater have other meaning in binding path. The solution is add event handler to **AutoGeneratingColumn** event in xaml:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Report.DefaultView}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  AutoGeneratingColumn="Dg_OnAutoGeneratingColumn"/>
```

and define the **Dg_OnAutoGeneratingColumn** method( maybe in your code behind):

```
        private void Dg_OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            var textCol = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
            if (textCol == null)
                return;
            var binding = textCol.Binding as Binding;
            if (binding == null)
                return;
            binding.Path = new PropertyPath("[" + binding.Path.Path + "]");
        }
```

P/S: I hope it can help you( I already tested from my side, and it is OK).

Answer (score 0):

Your source code look OK. Maybe you didn't update your dataGridView after binding the report DataTable.

I tried your code from my side, bind it with a DataGridView:

```
tbl_incomingrawmaterialform.DataSource = report;
tbl_incomingrawmaterialform.Update();
```

And it worked well.

Regard!

Comment: I have added an edit where I show how my data binding looks like, I don't know if that might have something to do with this not working for me. I would like to use MVVM pattern for this.